# Google Sheet - Send Email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api

I need my google sheet to send emails every time a condition becomes true.
In this case, every time value of C2 is lower than value of J2.
On the cell L2 there is the email address.

The code (found online and just edited)

```
function CheckPrice() {
  var LastPriceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Alerts").getRange("C2"); 
  var LastPrice = LastPriceRange.getValue();
  var EntryLimitRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Alerts").getRange("J2"); 
  var EntryLimit = LastPriceRange.getValue();
  var StockNameRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Alerts").getRange("B2"); 
  var StockName = LastPriceRange.getValue();
  // Check totals sales
  if (LastPrice < EntryLimit){
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Alerts").getRange("L2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
  
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'Ticker ' + StockName + ' has triggered the alert';
    var subject = 'Stock Alert';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

With this code I don't receive any error, but I don't even receive the email.
I granted permissions as requested when I run the script for the first time.

On L2 I put the same email address I granted permission (I send email to myself).
I did a try even putting a secondary email address I have.

Can you please show me what's wrong ?

Comment: How do you plan to trigger the function? onEdit only fires for user edits.

Comment: With a project's trigger to run every hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issues:**

- See the first lines of your code where you define `LastPrice`,
  `EntryLimit` and `StockName`. All of them are coming from the same
  range: `LastPriceRange`.
- I also removed all the unnecessary calls in your script. There is no
  need to call
  `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Alerts")` so
  many times when you can just put it in a variable and use that
  variable instead.
- Also, you don't need to define unnecessary
  variables. For example, you can get the value of a cell with one line:
  `sh.getRange("B2").getValue()`.

**Solution:**

```
function CheckPrice() {
  
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Alerts");   
  const LastPrice = sh.getRange("C2").getValue();
  const EntryLimit = sh.getRange("J2").getValue();
  const StockName = sh.getRange("B2").getValue(); 

  // Check totals sales
  if (LastPrice < EntryLimit){
    // Fetch the email address
    const emailAddress = sh.getRange("L2").getValue();
  
    // Send Alert Email.
    const message = 'Ticker ' + StockName + ' has triggered the alert';
    const subject = 'Stock Alert';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

If you want an email to be sent when you **edit** a particular cell, then you need to transform the aforementioned solution to an [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger. If you want a time basis trigger then you can just use the solution above directly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, now it works. Thought was not a problem to select multiple active spreadsheets if the cell was different.