# Trigger a google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Following this script [Google Sheet - Send Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992674/google-sheet-send-email)

I changed it a while and now it just loops every data in my sheet and then send the email.

The problem is that if I click the RUN button, it works, i receive the email.

But if I setup a trigger to that project, it doesn't work. The trigger looks executed without any error, but no emails are delivered.

Can someone explain why ?

this is the working code

```
 function SendEmailAlerts() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 20; // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 30)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var Ticker = row[1]; // Second column
    var currentPrice = row[2]; // 2 column
    var firstEntryLimit = row[9]; // 9 column
    var secondEntryLimit = row[8]; // 8 column
    var emailAddress = row[11]; // 11 column
    var ratioPick = row[13]; // 13 column
    var riskRatio = row[14]; // 14 column
    var rewardRatio = row[15]; // 15 column
    var FirstTarget = row[4]; // 4 column
    var rewardRatio2 = row[16]; // 16 column
    var FirstTarget2 = row[5]; // 5 column
    var FirstStop = row[6]; // 6 column
    var message = 'Ticker : #' + Ticker + '.\nEntry Price is any price around $' + firstEntryLimit + '.\nFirst Target : $'+FirstTarget+' (Reward '+rewardRatio+').\nSecond Target : $'+FirstTarget2+' (Reward '+rewardRatio2+').\nFirst Stop : $'+FirstStop+' (Risk '+riskRatio+').\nSignal ratio : '+ratioPick+'.';
    var subject = 'Alert on ' + Ticker + '';
    if (currentPrice < firstEntryLimit){
          if (currentPrice > secondEntryLimit){
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I already tried setting up the trigger in different hours [this is the trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu7XA.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem is using `getActiveSheet()` in conjunction with a time-driven trigger

- Time-driven triggers are independent of the UI and thus of the currently open sheet
- The will use a default sheet which might not be the one you have your data of interrest in

**Solution**

Replace

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`

by

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name);`

specifying the `id` and `name` of the spreadsheet and sheet you want the script to run on.

Comment: Nice catch ! I think that's the issue.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I receive the following Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp. (line 2, file "SendEmails")

code
`
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("123456").getSheetByName("Alerts");
`

Comment: Sounds like you are not retrieving the `id` correctly. If your spreadsheet url is something like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXX/edit#gid=1835181051`, then the spreadsheet `id` is the `XXX` part - a 44 character long combination of letters and numbers.